# need PHP regex number:number

Tags: php, regex

I need the follow regex for PHP:

```
Numbers:Numbers 
127.0.0.1:27015
```

Only for special characters and numbers.
The length is more or less different.

Comment: so what do you need to fetch?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I'm failing to see a question.

Comment: I suggest you look at a tutorial on regex, such as http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. Please don't ask people to spoonfeed you.

Comment: "_The lengh is more or less different._". What does that even mean? :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could use explode instead of regexp if that's the case.

```
$foo = "127.0.0.1:27015";

$ent = explode(':', $foo);
$ip = $ent[0];
$port = $ent[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
((\d{1,3}\.){3,3}\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})
```

Also it's very good to use http://www.regexper.com/

Comment: 15195:70111 is an correct ip?

Comment: then lets limit digits and groups amount: ((\d{1,3}\.){3,3}\d{1,3}):(\d+)

Answer (score 0):

whar do you want? regex expression like this?

```
^(([0-9]{1,2}|[12][0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]{1,2}|[12][0-9]{2})){3})[:]([123456]?[0-9]{1,4})$
```